# How can I load a AngularJS file in index.html dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

Each app has different modules, so they need to load different compiled js files in index.html as below.

Just find that it does not work. So is there a good way to do it? or need any callback to boot AngularJS app manually? Thanks.

```
<script>
    var appId = unescape(window.location.href).split('#/')[1].split('/')[0];
    loadComponent('../.tmp/client/scripts/' + appId + '.js');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequirejS for dynamic loading. You can combine Angular and RequireJS for better performing apps

Comment: Thank you, it is a good way to use requires.js. But I just want load a single js file, not to lazy load for each AngularJS module.